# Server validation for readonly textboxes - prevevt enter value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, security, disabled-control

I have a textbox in a mvc application which is marked as readonly (using JavaScript). However if user knows JavaScript, he can hit F12 and execute `$("#AmountBox").prop('readonly', false);`and enters some value the textbox and clicks on Submit button and changes the value of Amount in the database. How do I prevent users to enter value in a readonly or disabled textboxes? is there a way to do some Server Validation?

Comment: Everything a client sends to the server could be manipulated by the client before. Don't even have to be JavaScript. So you have to do server validation of the client data on the server to prevent those. But w/o knowing your context it is hard to tell how to do in this case

Comment: I agree I have an odd situation and I have to show the user the amount. if it is zero the user can enter a value into it and submit it, but if there is already a value in the database, it must be shown but not editable.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent overposting by adding a blacklist (or whitelist) to your controller action that accepts the POST.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "AmountBox")] SomeClass model)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need that read-only value, but don't want it changed, I think you either have to:

A) Save the value at the server before the form data is sent to the browser and compare when posted (a few ways to do this)

or

B) If you can, fetch the appropriate value only when posting and you don't need to send it to the client at all.

Comment: The value is saved in the database, if amount (the property) is zero (no value) the textbox is editable and user can enter a value into it but if the user already assigned a value to amount, he has no possiblity to edit it but he must see it.

Comment: Oh ok, then excluding it from the binding wouldn't work in this case.  Here's what I would do: On post, I would re-read the value from the DB before saving and if it's non-zero, then ignore the posted value (or overwrite the value from the client with the fetched value before update), otherwise update in the 'standard' way.  I think this should ensure tampered data is ignored. In fact you could even catch this situation when it happens and log a "hack" attempt.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description in the comment, you only want this Amount-data to be sent from client to server if it is zero before. Otherwise the amount is just shown. So to check for manipulated data from the client, the server needs to check if there is no amount value in the database and reject or ignore any amount data sent in this case. So something like

```
public void onDataReceived(Data data)
{
    if(db.GetAmountOfUserFromDB(data.userID) != null && data.AmountBox != null)
    {
       //just ignore the data.AmountBox value here or react with a message like "It is not allowed to change the amount"
    }
    else
    {
        //add data.AmountBox to db or whatever
    }
}
```